# How to know why my media is crashing on the Chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I'm implementing the Chromecast feature on an app of mine but I've been having a hard time figuring out a solution to my problem:

- One specific stream doesn't get started on Chromecast, even though it works fine on iOS's default media player. I've tried using the debug string on `mychromecastip:9222` but had no success.

I also checked the mim type, but it seems to be the same as my other working streams.

Any ideas on how to attack this problem?

Comment: huge files sometimes can cause to crash on chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what you mean by "tried that and had no success". In the most recent build, you are required to run your own app first and then try to attach the debugger to port 9222; if you do it before connecting your app, it will not work. In addition, make sure you have turned on logging (see the Debugging section [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver)) for details.

Comment: I set the "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates." on an iOS device, checked it through the MacOS application and the Android application, and then rebooted. When it was up I checked again in this three applications and it was correct, but still no access to my Chromecast. Then I reseted it to factory defaults and started the process all over again, just to hit the same "Webpage not available" as before. Am I missing any step?

Comment: Was your application running on chromecast when you tried to attach debugger? If so, then you need to double check your serial number.

Comment: I tried both with application running and without. What do you mean by double check the serial number?

Comment: When you create an App Id on the developer console, you have to add your cast device there as well. Adding cast device amounts to entering its serial number, so double check that you have entered the correct serial number.